# File-level DocBlock placement with namespace and declare(strict_types=1)

Tags: php, docblocks

What is the correct placement of the file-level DocBlock when using declare(strict_types=1) and namespace?

For example is the following correct or does the DocBlock go under the opening PHP tag?

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1)

/**
 * DocBlock
 */

namespace Xxx\Xxx;

use Xxx\Xxx;

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit;
}

/**
 *
 */
class Xxx {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Coding style rules are declared in some **PSR** (PHP Standard Recommendation) standards from [PHP-FIG](https://www.php-fig.org/). They are not officially related to the language but are followed by many PHP programmers and can be considered industry standards.

The question you ask is detailed in the [PSR-12 - 3rd part](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#3-declare-statements-namespace-and-import-statements):

> The header of a PHP file may consist of a number of different blocks. [...] Each block MUST be in the order listed below [...]
>
> - Opening <?php tag.
> - File-level docblock.
> - One or more declare statements.
>
> [...]

The example that follows shows the file-level docblock *before* the `declare` statement:

```php
<?php

/**
 * This file contains an example of coding styles.
 */

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Package;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have read PSR-12 several times, but I missed the file-level notation. I assume the whitespace above and below the DocBloc is a matter of preference?

Comment: @user23587753 From the same section in the document: *"If present, each of the blocks below MUST be separated by a single blank line"*.

Comment: "If present, each of the blocks below MUST be separated by a single blank line, and MUST NOT contain a blank line."

What is the difference between a, "single blank line" and "MUST NOT contain a blank line"?

Also by block, the opening PHP tag, declare() and use is a, 'block' as in everything in the list is a block?

Comment: @user23587753 Each item from the list is considered a "block". *"each of the blocks below MUST be separated by a single blank line"* means that you should not separate blocks with more than 1 blank line. I'm not sure for the *"MUST NOT contain a blank line"* part but I think it means that you can't put a blank line inside blocks (like, for example, between `use` statements).